# Three-fourths of an SVG circle works well only with a certain size

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a circle by creating 2 arcs with 2 path elements so if I rotate the second arc I can get 3/4, half or full circle.

This is what I am talking about.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- First half of the circle -->
  <path d="M100,0 A85,85 0 0,1 100,200"  class="first" stroke="purple" stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
  <!-- Second half of the circle -->
  <path d="M100,0 A100,100 0 0,0 100,200" class="second" stroke="purple" stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"/>
</svg>
```

With this size and coordinates it works like a charm.

And this is when I add "scale(2,2)" to the transform attribute:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- First half of the circle -->
  <path d="M100,0 A85,85 0 0,1 100,200"  class="first" stroke="purple" stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="rotate(0 100 100) scale(2,2)"/>
  <!-- Second half of the circle -->
  <path d="M100,0 A100,100 0 0,0 100,200" class="second" stroke="purple" stroke-width="1" fill="none" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)scale(2,2)"/>
</svg>
```

[Scaled Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IClYP.png)

I can't understand where's the issue, any help?

Comment: Put the scale before the transform.